# Implementing http404 in django

Tags: django, django-views

Implementing page not found in django and have looked at the documentation [404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception)

I do not get a page not found error as yet what ami doing here

In my code in urls i have done the following,

```
  url(r'^$', 'site_config.views.pagenotfound')
```

from django.http import Http404

```
 def pagenotfound(request):
   return render_to_response('polls/pagenotfound.html', {})
```

Comment: What's the problem. Do you get an error, a blank page, what?

Comment: for any link that i click  pagenotfound function is called even if it is a valid link

Comment: Do you have anything in your urls.py but that line?

Comment: This i have included in the main urls.py for the project where the other modules urls have been defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you handle 404 and 500 in django is: by default, in the templates directory, create a 404.html

If you need a custom handler, just add these to urls.py

```
handler404 = 'views.page_not_found_custom'    
handler500 = 'views.page_error_found_custom'
```

design the 404.html page the way you want