# Misconfigured custom HTTP error templates in Django project (404,500)

Tags: django, django-views

I am in Django HTTP error codes hell. Would be great if an expert can help me out of my misconfiguration.

My Django project runs with nginx as a reverse proxy coupled to a gunicorn application server.

**Requirement:**

I want a custom `Page not found` template to render (i.e. `404`) when a url pattern is entered that doesn't exist in my `urls.py`. Sounds simple enough, and is [well documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views).

I have already gone ahead and implemented this.

**The Problem:**

Assume `example.com` is my live project.

**1)** If I try to access  `https://example.com/asdfasdf` (i.e. unmatched, random gibberish) on my production server, it displays the `500` template instead of `404`.

**2)** Next, if I try to `curl` the said url pattern via  `curl -I https://example.com/asdfasdf/`, I see `200 OK` instead of `404` or `500`. Wth?

**3)** Moreover, if I try the same behavior with `Debug = True` on localhost, `404` is returned correctly (both template and HTTP error code are in consonance).

These 3 behaviors are quite perplexing.

**My configuration:**

I created `error_views.py` and inserted it in the folder where I keep my regular `views.py`. This error file contains:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def server_error(request):
    return render(request, '500.html')

def not_found(request):
    return render(request, '404.html')

def permission_denied(request):
    return render(request, '404.html')

def bad_request(request):
    return render(request, '404.html')
```

In my `urls.py` (kept in the same folder as `settings.py`), I added the following after all url patterns:

```
handler404 = 'my_app.error_views.not_found'
handler500 = 'my_app.error_views.server_error'
handler403 = 'my_app.error_views.permission_denied'
handler400 = 'my_app.error_views.bad_request'
```

I created `404.html` and `500.html`, and inserted them in the default `/templates/` directory.

In `settings.py`, I have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Lastly, my nginx conf dealing with this is as follows (placed within the `server` block in the virtual host file):

```
# Error pages
error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
    root /home/ubuntu/this_proj/project_dir/templates/;
}

location = /too_bad.svg {
    root /home/ubuntu/this_proj/project_dir/static/img/;
}
```

All of this is fairly regular stuff and I'm missing what I've misconfigured here. Can an expert guide me out of this mess?

Thanks in advance, and please ask for more information in case warranted.

*Note: I tried solutions provided in similar questions on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662928/django-creating-a-custom-500-404-error-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180281/implementing-http404-in-django/12180499#12180499). Needless to say, those misconfigurations were very different, displaying none of the symptoms I'm seeing.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a custom handler, you have to explicitly set the proper http status for the response object. If you don't set the status, the default is 200 OK.

```
def not_found(request):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)
```